# How to execute string as query inside a CTE in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using CTE like below... But I am getting an error like

> No column name was specified for column 1 of 'TempResult'.

Also here I am passing `@Query` from another stored procedure, and in this procedure I need to execute that `@Query` inside CTE `TempResult`.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SelectAllProjectPaging]      
    @CurrentPage int,                          
    @RecordsPerPage int,  
    @Column varchar(50),  
    @Query nvarchar(max)   
AS      
BEGIN      
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from      
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.      
    SET NOCOUNT ON;      

    DECLARE @query nvarchar(max)
    SET @query = 'ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ProjectList.ProjectId DESC) as RowNumber,' + @Query

    -- Insert statements for procedure here      
    DECLARE @FirstRecord int, @LastRecord int                       

    SELECT @FirstRecord = (@CurrentPage - 1) * @RecordsPerPage              
    SELECT @LastRecord = (@CurrentPage * @RecordsPerPage + 1);              

    WITH TempResult as              
    (                                
         Select @query
    )            
    SELECT TOP (@LastRecord - 1) *  
    FROM TempResult              
    WHERE RowNumber > @FirstRecord 
      AND RowNumber < @LastRecord;              

    SELECT COUNT(*) as count 
    FROM ProjectList          
 End
```

Comment: You can't. Unless you make the entire thing dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make the entire query with dynamic sql. something like this:

```
SET @query= 'WITH TempResult as              
             (                                
                SELECT + ' + @query + 
            ')            
             SELECT TOP (' + CAST((@LastRecord - 1) AS VARCHAR(20)) +
            ') * FROM TempResult              
             WHERE RowNumber > ' + CAST(@FirstRecord AS VARCHAR(20)) +
           ' AND RowNumber < ' + CAST(@LastRecord AS VARCHAR(20)) + '; '

EXECUTE @query
```

**Edit**

To the comment. Yes it should select what I can see. The `@query` is equals to:

```
set @query = 'ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ProjectList.ProjectId DESC) as RowNumber,'+ @query
```

Then you will need:

```
SELECT ' ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ProjectList.ProjectId DESC) as RowNumber,' + @query
```

Comment: @MartinSmith : Update the answer. Either I miss something or you?

Answer (score -1):

Your "With TempResult As" has to be extended a bit, containing the column names to be used.

Example

```
With TempResult (column1, column2, column3) as 
(
    select @query
)
```

Ref:

```
WITH expression_name [ ( column_name [,...n] ) ]
AS
    ( CTE_query_definition )
```

From http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx